# Intuit Partner Platform service unavailable error

Tags: .net, intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I install sample application of Intuit Partner Platform. I click "Add Accounts", select institution, then when i a'm trying to login i have error "Service Unavailable" when invoke DiscoverAndAddAccounts:

```
List<Credential> credentials = new List<Credential>();
foreach (Control control in LoginControls.Controls)
{
    if (control as TextBox != null)
    {
        Credential cred = new Credential();
        TextBox loginValue = (TextBox)control;
        cred.name = loginValue.Attributes["KeyName"];
        cred.value = loginValue.Text;
        credentials.Add(cred);
    }
}
creds.credential = credentials.ToArray();
instLogin.AnyIntuitObject = creds;

Challenges challenges = null;
ChallengeSession challengeSession = null;
AccountList accountList = svc.DiscoverAndAddAccounts(long.Parse(Request.QueryString["InstitutionID"].ToString()), instLogin, out challenges, out challengeSession);
```

Can anybody explain what's wrong? I write "test" in login and password.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question. Have you already created your application? Are you going through the SAML login flow? is that working correctly? That all has to happen before hand.

Comment: I would also try your XML request in the API explorer to make sure it isnt your code that is the issue. http://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer

Comment: Thanks, Jarred Keneally, very useful link.